# how to get local time in php 4

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone

I'm trying to get local time in php 4. Time i need is `America/Sao_Paulo` which is -3.0 hours from UTC.
So i tried the following code

```
echo date(" h:i:s A",time()-10800);//subtracting 3 hours(10800 seconds) from UTC
```

but i didn't get the exact time. This time is one hour less then the actual time. Am i doing something wrong?

In php 5

I can easily get the localtime by the following code

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
echo date(" h:i:s A",time());
```

I tried to use `putenv` but doesn't help

```
putenv("TZ=America/Sao_Paulo");
echo time();
```

Why was subtracting the time from UTC is incorrect?
How to get local time in php 4?

Comment: That would be because of your server maybe. Yourr server might not be configured with time of UTC.

Comment: @YashSodha Thanks. Can i get my serve UTC time r even if it is configured with some other time. So i can subtract/add it to get other timezones

Comment: Now that you know that your server is 1 hour more then UTC, you can subtract 14400 from `time()`

Comment: ok. Can i get UTC time directly. Because in some servers i won't know what might be the time set. @YashSodha

Comment: why dont you use `date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
` as you said in your question. Then you dont have to worry about anything.

Comment: PHP 4 reached [end of life in 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history).  Why are you still using it?  Just upgrade to PHP 5.